# In Project Manager In VS Code , I have saved 3 Projects. But it is not showing the list of that projects so that I can switch between the projects

Tags: vscode-extensions

Those projects which I have saved is showing in Projects.json file but the list of those projects is not showing below favourites so that I can switch between the projects. 
I tried by uninstalling it and again reinstalling it but nothing changes. 
I don't know how to fix this. Please help with this.
[image: my VS Code windows]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between projects, you can switch to the other projects directly by selecting 'Open Folder' from the file drop-down on the top.

Then, when you're done with the currently open project, save, close, and switch to the other project.

Comment: Ya what you said is right. But with this extension, we can manage project easily. So I want to resolve the issue what I got.

Comment: Which extension are you talking about?

Comment: project manager extension

Comment: My problem got solved after reinstalling Visual Studio Code.